# SQL Server Compact 3.5 Querying Operator

Tags: c#, sql, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012

i am trying to display the ID number by using this query

```
IQueryable<ToDoList> todolistQuery = from c in context.ToDoList where c.Title == NavigationContext.QueryString["Title"] & c.Description == NavigationContext.QueryString["Desc"] & c.Id == NavigationContext.QueryString["Id"] select c;
```

This Line:

```
c.Id == NavigationContext.QueryString["Id"]
```

has a red underline below it stating int ToDoList.Id Error: Operator '==' cannot be applied  to operands of type 'int' and 'string'

What have I actually done wrong? How do I solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your `NavigationContext.QueryString["Id"]` to `integer`:

```
c.Id == Convert.ToInt32(NavigationContext.QueryString["Id"])
```

And it should be fine.

Comment: Hi @Selman22, Thanks for the reply! I think this work but to make sure, I have this line below todolistToUpdate.Id = Id.Text; The Id.Text has the red underline too. I should convert it too?

Comment: @GeneLim yes, you cannot compare an integer with a string directly. you should convert one of them,if you want to compare integers,then convert your string to integer.if you want to compare strings, then convert integer variable to string.BTW your `todolistToUpdate.Id = Id.Text` is an assignment and the same thing applies for assignments.you can't assign an integer to a string directly.

Comment: I did this Convert.ToInt32(Id.Text); It works. Thanks! Now it make sense